# Windows store app not working

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-store-apps

I'm creating a windows store app to read write files.
I gave permissions for document library but still getting this error
**App manifest declares document library access capability without specifying at least one file type association**

The code snippet of my code:

```
  private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            String temp = Month.SelectedValue.ToString() + "/" + Day.SelectedValue.ToString() + "/" + Year.SelectedValue.ToString();  //((ComboBoxItem)Month.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(temp);
            Windows.Storage.StorageFolder installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
            StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt");
            var buffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(temp, Windows.Security.Cryptography.BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
            await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(sampleFile, buffer);
            buffer = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(sampleFile);
        }
```

Any other better approach is also acceptable.

**1.I don't have access to Skydrive. 
 2.Also don't want to use filepicker**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify file type association also.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx

Documents Library:

Note  You must add File Type Associations to your app manifest that declare specific file types that your app can access in this location.

you can find it in the app manifest, when you check `documents library` in `capabilites`, you have to fill in atleast one file type association under `Declarations` tab.

Comment: if your issue is resolved, please mark one answer as accepted, so others might be benefitted.

Comment: Not the exact answer thats why i dint mark it as answer i found a more specific answer to my question

Comment: @Pang thanks, it seems the domain is not owned anymore by the actual author, deleting the link

Answer (score 0):

Found exactly what i was looking for. File type associations was to be added in the app.manifest

For those who facing the same problem check this [link](http://mattduffield.wordpress.com/2012/10/13/developing-windows-8-documents-library/)